# Apt-get update connection failed, but wget is OK

Tags: apt, wget

I'm on a fresh install of bionic. This server is in Shanghai, China, and I've trying (and failing) to get `apt-get update` to work.

Here's the verbiage:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Meanwhile, `wget` is OK:

```
$ wget -SO /dev/null http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
--2018-09-20 01:52:06--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.152, 91.189.88.149, 91.189.88.161, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2018 01:52:07 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
  Last-Modified: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 23:38:40 GMT
  ETag: "3b180-56ac8e31ec000"
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Content-Length: 242048
  Cache-Control: max-age=0, proxy-revalidate
  Expires: Thu, 20 Sep 2018 01:52:07 GMT
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
Length: 242048 (236K)
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’

/dev/null                                                   100%[========================================================================================================================================>] 236.38K   243KB/s    in 1.0s

2018-09-20 01:52:08 (243 KB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [242048/242048]
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list` is fresh outta the oven, `env`'s output is typical, and I've read a couple other posts mentioning `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, but this file is not even available on the system, actually.

I'm stumped, anyone has a clue? I trawled through the 'net, the chatter suggests that it's a network issue, but how do I go about gathering evidence?

Comment: It would be great if you just paste the output instead of screenshots.

Comment: Well, I've fixed that. Tried again today, same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For servers in China, use China repos with https.

https://mirror.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/help/ubuntu/

edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and put those mirrors instead.

Comment: OMG, best thing since sliced bread!!